# Colocar um site dentro de outro como checkout light box

Tags: javascript

Sou desenvolvedor web e me deparei com um problema onde preciso exibir um formulário de cadastro dentro de outra pagina.
O cliente não deseja que seu usuário seja direcionada para nossa pagina, tentei instruir o mesmo a usar iframe mais isso resultou em uma experiencia mobile horrível.
Existe exemplos que conseguem fazer exatamente o que eu quero mais fora que são desenvolvidos em javascript não entendi muito bem como eles funcionam e não consegui achar termos de pesquisa para fazer algo parecido, somente olhando o código deles se torna difícil o entendimento pois possivelmente são minificados com webpack ou gulp.

Segue exemplos:

https://dev.pagseguro.uol.com.br/documentacao/pagamento-online/pagamentos/pagamento-lightbox/api-de-pagamentos-lightbox

ou

https://pagar.me/checkout/

ou

https://docs.mundipagg.com/docs/checkout-lightbox

Meu cliente no caso seguiria os mesmo exemplos, onde colocaria uma tag script e os dados de dependência, assim abrindo uma modal onde o conteúdo que fique la dentro seria controlado pelo meu site dando uma experiencia ao usuário dele um sistema distribuído que não muda de site.
Sei que não postei um erro ou código e não estou pedindo um código feito sim um direcionado de como fazer algo parecido.

Comment: Então brother, nesses casos, o processamento é realmente realizado no serviço (pagseguro, etc). Porém o formulário está no seu sistema. Não é um HTML externo não. Você deve usar os eventos do framework .js sobre o HTML que você irá montar ou o que eles sugerem...

Comment: Já pesquisou sobre o Include do PHP, ou a tag `<object>` do HTML ?

Comment: @DiegoSantos usar os eventos do framework seria montar o código dentro da pagina dele ? Por que no meu caso tenho clientes que usam framework js diferentes, teria que montar uma parte do meu site para cada framework, o que pensei foi uma chamativa em javascript o que pegaria vários frameworks de uma vez. E o mesmo só importaria esse código para o site dele, usando uma tag script apontada para meu servidor. Essa configuração que estou sem saber muito bem como iniciar.

Comment: Então, se você usar o .js deles, este próprio JS vai fazer requisições para o sistema deles diretamente. Isso já é um comportamento destes frameworks. tudo o que tem que fazer é configurar algumas informações, normalmente, tokens, etc. Você vai ter que montar apenas um HTML e ligar os pontos.

Answer (score 1):

Eu tentei de uma forma que talvez funcione mas não tenho a certeza que funcionará 100% pois certos plugins podem não carregar

```
<div id="load"></div>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#load").load("https://www.famalicaocanal.pt");
    })
</script>
```

Neste exemplo você poderá exibir aquele site na sua página apenas se tiver no topo da página o seguinte código no site que pretende apresentar

```
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Está à vontade para testar com esse `url` do site.